# Outh2 Token - Can i store the token in a session

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, okta

I have a short lived(both 20 mins) access token and refresh token and I want to store it in a session as below and will use it any where if required.

```
session.setAttribute(ApplicationConstants.OKTA_RESPONSE,token);
```

Please let me know whether this is correct approach or not.
If not please suggest a link or document where in I can refer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is session timeout value ?

Comment: Where do you want to store the token? On client-side or on resource server side?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your overall application architecture. It could be you are storing tokens of your client application in server for protection or it could be your server application which acts as the client.

Storing tokens secure is what mandate by specification. So in your case if you can protect session value when you are communicate with front end (ex:- JSP page) through established mechanism (ex:- SSL) I would say this is okay.